# describe function on a weighted data

Tags: r, weighted, describe

I was using describe to get mean value for gender distribution of my data. I have to mention that my data (STEM) has a weight column that is called "WG". The code I used to run looks this:

```
describe(STEM$SEX, weights= STEM96$WG, na.rm= TRUE)
```

and the output is as:

```
STEM$SEX : Your sex: 
        n   missing  distinct      Info      Mean 
353225.42 106307.68         2     0.648     1.316 

Value             1        2
Frequency  241660.0 111565.4
Proportion    0.684    0.316
```

However, as I try to run the same code again, I get this error:

```
describe(STEM$SEX, weights= STEM$WG, na.rm= TRUE)
```

> Error in describe(STEM$SEX, weights = STEM$WG, na.rm = TRUE) :
>   unused arguments (weights = STEM$WG, na.rm = TRUE)

I am not really sure what happened that R can not run this code any more. The only thing I did was to install and load some more packages for another calculations in the program. Is it possible installing other packages messed up with function "describe"?

Comment: what package did your  describe function came from?